# Disable onClick functionality using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using onClick event for the image.

When I am disable for the particular case, I didn't know exactly how can disable the `onClick` functionality using JavaScript.

Sample code:

```
<td>
    <a onClick="fun()">
        <html:img src="/caleder.jpg ... />
    </a>
</td>
```

calling fun:

```
function fun() {
    // in fun I want to disable the img and onClick functionality
    // i.e when I click that img, then it can't perform the onClick event.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The probably most efficient way since it removes the event listener:

```
<script>
  function fun(node) {
    document.getElementById(node).removeAttribute("onClick");
  }
</script>
```

Inside of the `onClick()` you need to place a `this` so it would be `onClick(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I usually just set a variable and put the events in the onClick handler inside a conditional statement. Set the variable on the first click, and next time it won't fire.

```
<script>
  var i = 0;
  function clickHandle(){
    if(i==0){
       //do stuff
       i=1;
  }
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can easy handle this issue with this code after you function see this codes

```
function disableClick() {
   document.getElementById('yourId you want disable on click').onclick = "";
}
```

and enable same this code

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMO.

```
function fun() 
{
    if (this.clicked == undefined)
    {
        this.clicked = true;
        // have fun
    }
    return false;
}
```