# Disable image link on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a image that links to a page. This is a process button which can take up to 20 seconds to run.
I want to prevent the user from pushing it more than once.

How would I write a Javascript that when the button is pushed, it would follow the hyperlink, but the link for the button would disable, and the image would change?

Comment: Can you clarify the process here, is it something like: user clicks button> 20 second delay on page while processing> user redirected to another page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable onClick functionality using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004058/disable-onclick-functionality-using-javascript)

Comment: It is just a standard link to another PHP page. That page can take up to 20 seconds (sometimes longer) to load. In the past, I've had users think that the thing is not responding, so they have clicked the button again, which has caused the system to reprocess (not good). I am going to add logic to stop this, but I want to stop it from the UI as well so the user can't click it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isSubmitted = false;
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    if ( ! isSubmitted ) {
      isSubmitted = true;
      var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("gold","red");
      $(this).attr("src", src);    
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function buttonClicked()
{
    document.getElementById('buttonImage').src = 'new-image.jpg';
    document.getElementById('buttonId').disabled = true;
}
</script>

<a id="buttonId" href="next-page.html" onclick="return buttonClicked()"><img id="buttonImage" src="image1.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like your "button" is the image that you click on...if that's true then you can use the following:

```
<a id="my_link" href="/page_to_vist_onclick"><img id="my_image"></a>
```

Then your javascript would be:

```
document.getElementById('my_link').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('my_link').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("my_image").src='the_path_to_another_image';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On click, remove the `href` attribute from the `a` element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple one for you

in your JS

```
function Create(){ 
document.write('<INPUT disabled TYPE="button" value="Click Me!">'); 
}
```

in your HTML

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="Create()">
```

If you are ready to use jQuery, then here is another solution.

```
$("selectorbyclassorbyIDorbyName").click(function () {
  $("selectorbyclassorbyIDorbyName").attr("disabled", true).delay(2000).attr("disabled", false);
});
```

select the button and by its id or text or class ... it just disables after 1st click and enables after 20 Milli sec

Works very well for post backs n place it in Master page, applies to all buttons without calling implicitly like `onclientClick`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
<script>
function hideme()
{
    $("#buttonImage").hide();
}
</script>

<a id="buttonId" href="next-page.html" onclick="return hideme()"><img id="buttonImage" src="image1.jpg"></a>
```

if you don't want to hide image please use this..

```
$('#buttonImage').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
});
```

That will prevent the default behaviour of a hyperlink, which is to visit the specified href.

Comment: This will hide the image though? I don't want to hide the image, just want to disables its href attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Let's make a jquery plugin :

```
    $.fn.onlyoneclick=function(o){
      var options=$.extend({src:"#"},o);
      $(this).click(function(evt){
        var $elf=$(this);
        if( $elf.data("submitted") ){
          evt.preventDefault();
          return false;        
        }
        $elf.attr("src", typeof(options.src) == 'function' ? 
                          options.src($elf.attr("src"))
                        : options.src
                ).data("submitted",true);
      });
    }

    $(".onlyoneclick").onlyoneclick({
      src : function( src ){
          return  src.replace("gold","red");
      }
    })
```

on any button that should trigger only once :

```
    <button ... class="onlyoneclick">tatatata... </button>
```

Answer (score -2):

its simple...just one line of code :)

```
Onclick return false.
```